# Other meaning of 訪れる

Tags: translation, usage

I am translating some Japanese Documents to English and I came across this text:

> 66歳に到達した日以降に最初に訪れる3月末まで

So far I have:

> Until the end of March...on or after the day of turning 66 years old

How should one translate this text: 最初に訪れる, in order for it to fit the given text?

I have read about 訪れる [here](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A8%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B#.E5.8B.95.E8.A9.9E).

Until the end of the coming March? then how about the 最初に

Until the end of the first incoming March?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's the second sense for 訪れる in Wiktionary:

> 季節・状況などがやってくる。

Other dictionaries give similar definitions.  Here's the relevant sense from 広辞苑:

> （ある時期・状況などが）やってくる。「春が訪れる」「世界に平和が訪れる日」

So 最初に訪れる３月末 would mean something like "the first March 31 that arrives", although *arrive* is a bit literal and we probably don't need to use it in translation, so your larger phrase would perhaps look something like this:

> "by/until the first March 31 after [you] turn 66 years old"

I can't really make the translation more natural since you didn't supply much context, or even a complete sentence, but hopefully it gets the meaning across :-)

Comment: I see. Sorry for not providing more context but your translation more or less fits the document I am translating. どもありがとうございます。